# Salesforce Objects available in Social Tables

Tags: salesforce, social-tables

My question has to do with the Salesforce integration in Social Tables and is two-fold: 1. Am I correct that only objects belonging to Contacts can be imported to Social Tables? 2. Is further integration under development?

To clarify, at present it appears that Social Tables pulls contacts from Campaigns, but does not pull other campaign data - only data stored in Contact records.

To really make use of the Salesforce integration, we'd like to import event data to Social Tables fields (e.g. Table #, Seat # etc). (Our use case is a seated fundraising breakfast.) Intuitively, that would mean Campaign Member in Salesforce would need to be imported to Social Tables along with Contacts (event-specific data can't be stored that in Contact records, since the guest data and data types would vary for different events).

Similarly, it would be great to have the option to import only the contacts in a campaign that have a specific status or "Attending?" value. I know it's possible to map Salesforce fields to event-specific fields in Social Tables, so maybe I'm missing something...thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer those for you.

> 1. Am I correct that only objects belonging to Contacts can be imported to Social Tables?

This is almost correct, for a given CampaignMember of a Campaign we are currently pulling all Lead or Contact fields (depending on the type of the CampaignMember). This does not include CampaignMember fields.

> 2. Is further integration under development?

My team is responsible for Check-In and although our focus is currently not on adding SF Integration features, we weigh customer feedback very heavily when revisiting our roadmap. You make a very valid point with including CampaignMember fields with the import and I will communicate this to our product team so they can handle accordingly.

Importing a subset of members is another great feature request that we will note. Once we have CampaignMember fields included you could accomplish this by importing all members then selecting users with unwanted statuses and deleting. Not the best but will work.

Thanks for reaching out with the fantastic feedback and hope this helps answer your questions!

Comment: Thanks Ben...it does, though it's not the answer I hoped for. :) It would be so great to make use of existing Campaign Member fields to map directly to Social Tables so we could really make use of its capabilities (grouping, tags etc) without multiple intermediate steps (e.g. creating sub-campaigns and multiple imports). This would add so much value to the integration by making it more efficient and streamlined. Please let me know if you'd be open to discussing further how this integration could be optimized.

Comment: VERY glad I found this - documentation is very poor and fact that we can't use campaign member fields means this integration will simply not work for most use cases. Also, agree that mapping filter would be helpful for large campaigns.